# Force redownload/completely clean environment

Tags: go, build

First off, I have no experience with go, I'm just trying to build a project from github.

My problem: When I use `go build` in a cloned go project I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
transform.go:28:2: cannot find package "github.com/disintegration/imaging" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go/src/github.com/disintegration/imaging (from $GOROOT)
        /home/marcus/go/src/github.com/disintegration/imaging (from $GOPATH)
imageproxy.go:34:2: cannot find package "github.com/gregjones/httpcache" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go/src/github.com/gregjones/httpcache (from $GOROOT)
        /home/marcus/go/src/github.com/gregjones/httpcache (from $GOPATH)
transform.go:29:2: cannot find package "github.com/muesli/smartcrop" in any of:
        /usr/lib/go/src/github.com/muesli/smartcrop (from $GOROOT)
        /home/marcus/go/src/github.com/muesli/smartcrop (from $GOPATH)
```

What happened: I broke everything because I started deleting random directories hoping to fix a different issue I was having. I deleted my `~/go` directory, and the `~/.cache/go-build` directory.

What I've tried: So far, besides the deletions that caused the problem, I've tried `go clean -cache -modcache`; Adding the `-r` flag produces the same errors as above. `go build -a` also produces the same errors. I have also tried reinstalling go with `pacman -S go`.

My `go env` is:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/marcus/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/marcus/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build315222728=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I know I was doing things unexpected, but I'm surprised Go is struggling here. How can I make Go realize that the packages are not present *and that it should fix that by downloading them*? Or, how can I clean my environment to remove whatever artifacts are still present that are making Go think the packages should still exist?

Comment: You have to specifically `go get` each of the packages it is saying are not on your system (e.g. `go get github.com/disintegration/imaging`). It does not make any attempt to retrieve them automatically. That would be VERY BAD from a security standpoint if it just arbitrarily downloaded code from the internet and compiled it.

Comment: I'll try that, but I'm still curious why go isn't doing it automatically now? When I first cloned the project and ran `go build` it started downloading all of the packages. What artifact is still present that is preventing go from getting them?

Comment: Because I could make a legit library, get thousands of people to use it, then decide to be malicious after hooking people, add __one line__ to any of the source files to import a malicious external repo, and it would then automatically retrieve it, compile it, and subsequently people would run it. I'm pretty sure you remember incorrectly, as I can't imagine it ever automatically downloading 3rd party code.

Comment: Perhaps because I'm new to Go, I'm misunderstanding the output, but this is what happened the first time: https://pastebin.com/GAPPZRu7

Answer (score 1):

After reading up to respond to comments, I stumbled upon the `go mod verify` command which appears to have fixed my issues.

Comment: To add to this, it tells you the directory that's been changed so you can delete it, then when you build again, it will go back to what it's supposed to be.